# How to set background color to whole window (not according to content)? See Image below

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When I create the new page & set `background-color: black`, it is coming according to content, not on the whole window.

I don't want to put that property into HTML.

I mean size of the body is generating according to content.

How can I fix that?

I can't put `position: fixed` in the body because sometimes I have to scroll on other pages & also I have footer stick to the bottom.

**This is HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-cloak>
    <notifications-bar class="notifications"></notifications-bar>

    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
        <ng-include src="'app/layout/header.html'"></ng-include>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer_body">
        <ng-include src="'app/layout/footer.html'"></ng-include>
    </footer>
    <spinner></spinner>

</body>
</html>
```

**This is CSS:**

```
html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
     }

html {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

body
    {
       min-height: 100% !important;
       margin-bottom:60px;
    }

.footer_body {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px; /* height of footer */
  background-color: #666666;
}
```

[image: This Image shows the footer is good at the bottom but then there is a gap in between body & footer]

Comment: "I don't want to put that property into HTML". Why?

Comment: I have other pages which have some different colors in the background. So If I put Chartuese Color in HTML or body it will reflect in my all other pages which have a white background. As you can see my code <ng-view> is calling all my pages Under MainCtrl.

Answer (score 0):

Update you CSS property html body background color like this

```css
html, body {
background-color:#aadb1e;
     }
```

Comment: Effecting my other pages background color. I think some Error in HTML body. 
<body ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
        <ng-include src="'app/layout/header.html'"></ng-include>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer_body">
        <ng-include src="'app/layout/footer.html'"></ng-include>
    </footer>
</body>
because when I put background-color on the body this filling the whole window but when I put a background color to [ng-controller] .div its coming according to content.

Comment: if you have different color for other pages then give background color for the parent class , in you case add a new class to <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main" class="giveColor">
in CSS .giveColor{background-color:#aab1e;}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a `background-color` to `.html` in your `css file` ?

```css
html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
     }

html {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 100%;
    }

body
    {
       min-height: 100% !important;
       margin-bottom:60px;
    }
    
.special-bg{
  background-color: cyan;
}

.footer_body {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  height: 60px; /* height of footer */
  background-color: #666666;
}
```

```html
<html class='special-bg'>
  <body>
    <notifications-bar class="notifications"></notifications-bar>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
        <ng-include src="'app/layout/header.html'"></ng-include>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer_body">
        <ng-include src="'app/layout/footer.html'"></ng-include>
    </footer>
    <spinner></spinner>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.!! But that will effect my other pages where I have some other background color.!

Comment: So easy, set a special `class` for the `html` of this page, and give this class the `background-color`

Comment: That's not worked. If you are checking my code I am calling Header & Footer inside Body via ng-controller!! So I have a header.html & Footer.html. But I am calling other pages in between using [ng-view].  I have other Pages which have content to scroll on the page so footer at the bottom, color is good. But this is the problem with the pages have less content.

Comment: It does not matter what pages you call in your body, just give this page a class for it's `<html>` tag, and define this class in your `.css file`. Is the page `html & content` rendering dynamic?